# ASPNETDB and ASPSTATE database. How to change the connectionstrings?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, iis-5

I have two ASP-specific SQL Server databases

1) ASPState - To store session state 
2) ASPNETDB - To store Security/Role stuff.

In my web.config, I am specifying the connection string used to identify the location of the APState database:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="server=(local)\sql2008b;uid=sa;pwd=iainttelling;" timeout="120"/>
```

Where is the conenction string specified for the ASPNETDB database? I am trying to point it to a db on a remote server.

I have a feeling it is somewhere in IIS orthe Machine Config. I'd like to add it to my *WEB.CONFIG* Could someone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a connection string in `connectionStrings` section and then override role/membership settings like this:

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
        <providers>
            <add
                name="SqlRoleManager"
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
                connectionStringName="DefaultSqlConnection"
                applicationName="myApp" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipManager" >
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add
                name="SqlMembershipManager"
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                connectionStringName="DefaultSqlConnection"
                applicationName="myApp"
                passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx)